# When disabling an element with Javascript it doesn't apply styles

Tags: javascript, css

In my CSS I am trying to style some `input`s with the following:

```
input[disabled="disabled"], input[disabled="true"] {
    [... styles ...]
}
```

This works fine and dandy when I add `disabled="disabled"` straight to the HTML, however when I run the following JS:

```
document.getElementById('id').disabled = true;
```

The form field is disabled (i.e. can't focus it), but the styles are not changed. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById('id').disabled = true;` only adds the keyword attribute `disabled`, while the css is looking for the attribute `disabled=true`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
input[disabled] {
  /* styles */
}
```

It works fine here: http://jsbin.com/asifih/1/edit